# How to increment a constant value with a value entered in Input textfield in material- ui

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a field using Input component of material-ui:

```
<Input
  placeholder="0.00"
  value={rate}
  onChange={event => {
    this.setState({
      `obj.rate`,
      event.target.value 
    });
  }}
/>
```

So, whenever I am entering a rate into this field,

- 1) it should automatically append ".00" at the end (For example: I entered 71, it should display 71.00)
- 2) If I am entering a value starting with a point (.), then digits should enter after point and can be entered upto 2 digits. (For example: I entered .2 ===> It should display 0.20, if I entered .34 ====> 0.34)

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to think as a calculator. In a field, if you are trying to format it. Don't let your user to type points. That's away complicate to mix number with other characters.

Let's try a mask. Please take a look on this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-paper-0ybrz

Basically, we're going to define a function to format whatever your user input or past in the field.

```
export function decimalChangeHandler(event) {
  event.target.value = formatDecimal(event.target.value);
}

export function formatDecimal(value) {
  if (typeof value === "undefined") return;
  value = value.toString();
  value = value.replace(/\D/g, ""); // only numbers
  value = value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{14})$/, "$1,$2");
  value = value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{11})$/, "$1,$2"); // for 11 digits
  value = value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{8})$/, "$1,$2"); // for 8 digits
  value = value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{5})$/, "$1,$2"); // for 5 digits
  value = value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/, "$1.$2"); // put 2 digits
  return value; // return the value
}
```

Now we will call this functions when the field changes:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChangeValue = event => {
    setValue(decimalChangeHandler(event));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Mask Example</h1>

      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
          label="Value"
          value={value}
          placeholder="0.00"
          onChange={handleChangeValue}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: After first digit, other digits are coming after a point. Ex: I wanted to enter Rs 234, so it should have displayed Rs 234.00, instead it displayed Rs 2.34

Comment: That's an input mask behavior. Specially if you want to add the R$. I believe you want to add the currency before. Is that correct? if your user inputs 234 it will add the points as soon as your user types. returning 2.34. But if you add zeros or any number it will show the 23.40 and consequently 234.00. That's the normal behavior.

Comment: Yes, i have to add currency before the value. If its a normal behavior, then its fine for me. :). Thanks a ton!

Comment: To add the currency, please.Try to do something like: return value !== "" ? `R$ ${value}` : value; `